# The initial render takes 5 days, but the next take 2 minutes? Why?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Okay, I have been living with this problem for a long time, and it's no big deal.
But the problem is when I click render, the initial render is estimated to take 5 hours to 5 days, and I'm pretty sure it's planning on doing exactly that because it's super SLOW.
But if I cancel the render and start it again, it might take 2-5 minutes.

I have no idea why, and this has been happening for maybe 5 months. This hasn't been a major issue because now I have just implemented this extra step in my workflow XD

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?
Btw it doesn't matter if it's the first, last, or some random frame. It's just the initial render that is super slow. The project size can also vary, but it looks like it has to reach a minimum size, so rendering 1 cube won't take 5 days.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Look under _Render Properties > Performance_ and see if the "Persistent data" button is checked - this option can speed up re-renders, but can also eat up memory. Un-check it if it is.

Comment: Yup, sounds exactly like persistant data effects. But "5 hours to 5 days"? i have never seen blender give an interval estimate nor one in days?

Comment: @L0Lock Oh, you happy being. A few years ago when I had no dedicated GPU and just a bad CPU, trying to render smoke simulations could actually make my Blender tell me estimated times of 2+ days. But no interval of course, only the estimated time was fluctuating between hours and days... I guess that's what he meant.

Comment: Not sure about happiness there, I never have been able to afford rendering even a single frame for days, I have always either optimized or even downgraded things to fit my time budget x)

Comment: My bad XD It's not showing a time estimate, it just sometimes says 5 hours but it might also jump to something ridiculous like 120 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Look under *Render Properties > Performance* and see if the *Persistent Data* button is checked.

This option can speed up re-renders, but can also eat up memory. Un-check it if it is.